# anova() does not display an F-value or p-value when comparing two models

Tags: r, multiple-regression, anova

I'm working with the "iris" dataset in R (version 4.0.3), and I'm trying to find the best model for predicting `Sepal.Length`.  Over the course of my analysis, I've come across two models that I can't compare using `anova()`:

```
colnames(iris) <- c("sl", "sw", "pl", "pw", "species")

model1 <- lm(sl ~ pl + sw + species + pl:sw + pl:species, iris)
model2 <- lm(sl ~ I(pl^2) + I(sw^2) + species + I(pw^2) + I(pl^2):I(sw^2), iris)
```

When I run `anova(model2, model1)`, I get this:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: sl ~ I(pl^2) + I(sw^2) + species + I(pw^2) + I(pl^2):I(sw^2)
Model 2: sl ~ pl + sw + species + pl:sw + pl:species
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq F Pr(>F)
1    143 12.591                      
2    142 12.754  1  -0.16296
```

But this isn't the case for other models, such as `anova(model2, lm(sl ~ ., iris)`:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: sl ~ I(pl^2) + I(sw^2) + species + I(pw^2) + I(pl^2):I(sw^2)
Model 2: sl ~ sw + pl + pw + species
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F   Pr(>F)   
1    143 12.591                                
2    144 13.556 -1  -0.96513 10.961 0.001178 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Why can't the first two models be compared using `anova()`
?

Comment: It looks to me like the models probably aren't nested.

Comment: @Glen_b Yep, that's it.  Can't believe I didn't notice that.  Thank you!

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Glen_b's comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/594329/anova-does-not-display-an-f-value-or-p-value-when-comparing-two-models#comment1099734_594329), your models are not nested. `model1` contains an interaction term `pl:species` which is not present in `model2`, and `model2` obviously contains terms that are not in `model1`. In such cases, the $F$ test statistic does not necessarily follow an $F$ distribution, so we can't simply calculate a $p$ value.

If you change `model1` by removing the problematic `pl:species` interaction, `anova()` will give you a $p$ value:

```
> model1 <- lm(sl ~ pl + sw + species + pl:sw, iris)
> anova(model2, model1)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: sl ~ I(pl^2) + I(sw^2) + species + I(pw^2) + I(pl^2):I(sw^2)
Model 2: sl ~ pl + sw + species + pl:sw
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F   Pr(>F)   
1    143 12.591                                
2    144 13.545 -1   -0.9535 10.829 0.001259 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: I had forgotten that they had to be nested.  I guess all of the other models I was comparing just happened to be nested, because this was the only one that had that issue.  Anyway, thanks for the help!